# How to convert an unsigned char* into char*

Tags: c, string

I want to convert unsigned char* to char*, print the value and again convert char* to unsigned char*. How can I do that ?

Comment: Forced conversions are done by casting in C. But, casting should be avoided unless absolutely necessary. Why do you need to do this? Your question should provide more context.

Answer (score 2):

Byte arrays can be interpreted as arrays of `char`, `unsigned char` or `signed char`.

Most string functions from the C library take arguments of type `char *` or `const char *` and assume the arrays pointed to by such pointers have a null terminator (a null byte indicating the end if the string, conventionally written as a the null character constant `'\0'`).

As long as your array of `unsigned char` has a null terminator, it is harmless to cast its address as `(char *)` or `(const char *)` when passing it to these library functions.

For example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
    unsigned char buf[256];
    char *p;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(buf); i++) {
        buf[i] = (i + 1) & 255;
    }
    printf("length of array: %d\n", (int)strlen((char *)buf));
    printf("complete character set: >>>%s<<<\n", (char *)buf);

    p = (char *)buf;
    printf("char type is %s by default\n", p[128] < 0 ? "signed" : "unsigned");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: How is this different than using `reinterpret_cast`?

Comment: @Fred: `reinterpret_cast` is a C++ concept.

Answer (score 0):

```
unsigned char x = 0xFF;
unsigned char *p = &x;

printf("Signed value - %d\n", *((char *)p));
printf("Unsigned value - %u\n", *p);
```

But I agree with commenter that such casting should be avoided if possible.

Comment: I didn't get the reason for downvote. Can you explain?